# i give rename csv location path to variable in python , it gives errror unicodedecodeError

Tags: python-3.x

i give rename csv location path to variable. it give errror unicodedecodeError

```
def __init__(self):
    self.ticker_list_filename = 'E:/materials/AI/github/Sentiment-Analysis-in-Event-Driven-Stock-Price-Movement-Prediction-master/input/tickerList.csv',

UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x90 in position 652: character maps to <undefined>
```

Comment: The error occurs when you open the file, right? Please show the whole code and more importantly the whole traceback including the error.

Comment: I think you might be missing `encoding="utf8"` but cannot comment until the entire code is shown

Comment: how to give  missing encoding="utf8" to this formate          
                                                                                        
self.ticker_list_filename = 'E:/materials/AI/github/Sentiment-Analysis-in-Event-Driven-Stock-Price-Movement-Prediction-master/input/tickerList.csv',

Comment: The encoding must be passed when opening the file, not when defining its path. Check duplicate Q/A.